# Concatenate multiple value from column into row without add some value

Tags: oracle, concatenation

I have to give a description of the possible values for each rows into field and 
I don't have to show the BASE class.

```
    SELECT A.COD_PUNTO, 
wm_concat(SUBSTR(C.DESCARDPRFCFR, 22, 10)) AS LIST
FROM FR_VALID_PROF A 
    INNER JOIN PUN B  
        ON A.COD_PUNTO = B.COD_PUNTO
    INNER JOIN DANAFR C 
        ON A.CODPRF = C.CARDPRFCFR
GROUP BY A.COD_PUNTO
```

My result is:

```
COD_PUNTO  |  LIST
---------------------
0          | BASE, SUNDAY
1          | BASE, SUNDAY, ORANGE, ORANGE
2          | BASE, BASE, SUNDAY, SUNDAY, ORANGE, ORANGE, ORANGE
```

but I would like

```
COD_PUNTO  |  LIST
---------------------
0          | SUNDAY
1          | SUNDAY, ORANGE
2          | SUNDAY, ORANGE
```

I can't use listagg, for the one I used wm_concat.

Comment: Execute `SELECT A.COD_PUNTO, SUBSTR(C.DESCARDPRFCFR, 22, 10) AS input
FROM FR_VALID_PROF A 
    INNER JOIN PUN B  
        ON A.COD_PUNTO = B.COD_PUNTO
    INNER JOIN DANAFR C 
        ON A.CODPRF = C.CARDPRFCFR` to see which values are returned. Probably more values are returned as you expected. Probably you will have to excule `BASE` with `WHERE SUBSTR(C.DESCARDPRFCFR, 22, 10) <> 'BASE'`. Then you can use `distinct` in the concatenation to eliminate duplicates: `wm_concat(distinct SUBSTR(C.DESCARDPRFCFR, 22, 10))`. But it is difficult to say without seeing your table data.

Comment: Keep in mind that `WM_CONCAT` does not exist in 12c.  You will have to upgrade your code to something else eventually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a subquery and DISTINCT clause:

```
SELECT COD_PUNTO, wm_concat(SUBSTR(DESCARDPRFCFR, 22, 10)) AS LIST
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT A.COD_PUNTO, C.DESCARDPRFCFR
  FROM FR_VALID_PROF A 
  INNER JOIN PUN B  
        ON A.COD_PUNTO = B.COD_PUNTO
  INNER JOIN DANAFR C 
        ON A.CODPRF = C.CARDPRFCFR
)
WHERE DESCARDPRFCFR <> 'BASE'
GROUP BY COD_PUNTO
```